# Dead lock in SBCL Thread

Tags: multithreading, common-lisp, sbcl

I was coding up a script for a research project using SBCL, and this is the first time I tried SB-TREAHD. Each thread will call external shell command several times, for which sb-ext:run-program is used.

The problem is that whenever ext:run-program is presented, the program can run into dead lock (where I did not use anything like mutex excplicitly). I experiment it for a while and couldn't find any solution. A simplified version of the code which can still make the dead lock happen is as follows:

```
(use-package :sb-thread)

;;; Global Settings
(defparameter *path-num* 4)
(defparameter *testing* nil)
(defparameter *training* nil)
(defparameter *shared-folder* "shared")
(defparameter *template* "template.conf")
(defparameter *pwd* (namestring (truename ".")))


;;; Utilities
(defmacro compose-file-name (&rest parts)
  "compose a filename under current *pwd*"
  `(concatenate 'string *pwd* 
        ,@(mapcar (lambda (x) `(format nil "/~a" ,x))
              parts)))

(defun run-command (command &optional args)
  "run a shell comamnd and reflect the stdout on screen."
  (let* ((process (sb-ext:run-program command args
                                     :output :stream
                                     :wait nil))
         (output (sb-ext:process-output process)))
    (loop for line = (read-line output nil)
       while line do (format t "~a~%" line))))



(setf *testing* '("1" "2" "3" "4"))
(setf *training* '("5" "6" "7" "8"))


(defun gen-conf (path-id target labeled)
  "Prepare the configuration file"
  (format t "[~a]: ~a~%" path-id target)
  (let ((current-dir (compose-file-name path-id)))
    (run-command "/bin/cp" (list "-f" (compose-file-name *shared-folder* *template*)
                                 (format nil "~a/Prediction.conf" current-dir)))
    (with-open-file (*standard-output* (format nil "~a/Prediction.conf" current-dir)
                           :direction :output
                           :if-exists :append)
      (format t "--estimate ~a~%" path-id))))


(defun first-iteration ()
  (loop for i below 20
       do (gen-conf (thread-name *current-thread*) (format nil "~a" i) (list "123" "456"))))


;;; main
(defun main ()
  (let ((child-threads (loop for i below *path-num*
                          collect (make-thread 
                   (lambda () (first-iteration))
                   :name (format nil "~a" i)))))
    (loop for th in child-threads
       do (join-thread th))))


(main)
```

where in (main) 4 threads are created, and each of them will run (first-iteration), and in (first-iteration) it calls (gen-conf) several times which involves both (sb-ext:run-program) and file I/O.

I thought maybe the dead lock is due to incorrectly using of sb-thread, but just by looking at the SBCL manual I cannot find out the correct way. Any suggestion will be helpful.

btw, to run the program, get http://pages.cs.wisc.edu/~breakds/thread.tar.gz which have all the required directories/files created.

Thank you!

Comment: Doesn't deadlock for me. What version of SBCL are you using? I believe there have been significant improvements to threading over the last year.

Comment: Thank you for testing the code! I tried it with both sbcl 1.0.53 on a university workstation, as well as sbcl 1.0.56 on my debian laptop. I guess 1.0.56 is a pretty new version? However I forgot to say that the deadlock DOES NOT happen every time I run it, but with a very high possibility according to my experiment, more than 2 out of 3 if I set the thread number to be close to the cores I've got on that machine.

Comment: Report to the sbcl user mailing list, perhaps?